# Describe table with sorted columns

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to describe postgres table using psql. I read this [article](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS) and now I can use this structure

```
\d+ table_name
```

With this function I could display all columns and indexes related to table. But is it possible to show all table columns with specified order ? For Example I want to display columns sorted by name in desc order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'your_table' 
ORDER BY column_name DESC;
```

As the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/information-schema.html) says:

> The information schema consists of a set of views that contain information about the objects defined in the current database.

In this *columns* table you will find more information as

- ordinal position of the column within the table
- column default
- data type
- if the column is nullable
- scale e precision for numeric fields
- limit of length for character fields
- ....

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/infoschema-columns.html) for a complete list

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing this information from the `information_schema.columns` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
AND table_name = 'your_table'
ORDER BY column_name;
```